# Programmatically Refresh/Update Sql Agent Job Steps Use of Environment Variables in SSIS Pkgs

Tags: sql-server, ssis, environment-variables

After changing some variables in an Integration Services Catalog Environment the new values hadn't been applied to certain SQL Agent Job Steps.

Some of the values in the Step were put in manually and are not automatically updated with the new Environment variable. The ones that had a previous Environment variable already applied seem to grab the new value that was changed from the Environment when the Job is run.

The ones with the manual entries retained the manual text when the Job was run.

I have quite a number of steps that are in that boat and I'm looking for a way to programmatically "Refresh/Update" the entry in the Job Step Properties - Configuration - Parameters - Value to point to the Environment variable instead of retaining the manual entry.

[image: Job Step Properties]

I can get the Job Step to grab the new Environment variable by removing the bold text in the value column (shown in pink) then closing the Job and reopening, but this is quite cumbersome for the number of these I need to do and of course is not programmatic.

I looked at msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep, but as I understand it I'd need to supply the string value for "command" which has several fields and is expected to take some dev and testing to get the formatting correct, yet another cumbersome alternative (yep, I'm a lazy sort that way).

I am hoping that there is a function/stored procedure/etc. that does basically what I did in the Job Step but does it without my needing to build the string and just updates the Job Step from the Environment applied.